# How to know if the code in the overloaded assignment operator executes?

Tags: c++, assignment-operator

I have the following code:

```
class Sales_item {
     public:
     int ii;
         Sales_item& operator=(const Sales_item &item)
     {
        cout << "Inside assignment\n"; // Line 1
        ii = item.ii;
        return *this; // Line 2
     }
};
```

Then, I did:
(just an example)

```
Sales_item s;
Sales_item s1 = s;
```

But the `Line 1` did not execute. How can I "see" code inside the overloaded assignment to get executed? For example, there might be complicated code and I want to debug? I have tried to set a breakpoint at Line 1, but the program did not jump into that breakpoint.

Why `Line 2` returns `*this`? I have tried to change to `void` and got the same results. What's the  difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're initializing `s1`, not assigning to it.

```
Sales_item s1 = s;
```

calls the compiler-generated **copy constructor**. It is equivalent to:

```
Sales_item s1(s);
```

You need:

```
Sales_item s1;
s1 = s;
```

Why `Line 2` returns `*this`? - That's the idiomatic way of implementing the assignment operator, and I suggest you stick to it. It facilitates method and operation chaining.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding question 2: You return *this in order to enable chained assignments like s1 = s2 = s3 = ...